# How to add a map to a light source in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

So I am trying to make a simple solar system, and I'm trying to figure out how to make the Sun a light source as well as adding a map of an image to it to make it look like the sun. The code I have makes it a light source, but I can't see the sun, it's just a black circle. Any thoughts that could help?

```
        //Adding the sun
        geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 32, 32 );
        light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 5000 );
        material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
            // emissive: 0xff00ff,
            // emissiveIntensity: 1,
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun.jpg'),
            color: 0xffffff,
            side: THREE.FrontSide
        });
        light.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1));
        light.position.set(0,0,0);
        light.castShadow = true;
```

Here is what the scene looks like, as you can see the Earth has light from the Sun.

[image]

This is the code that makes the sun and then I add it to the scene. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `skinning: true`

```
geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 32, 32 );
light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 5000 );
material1 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
    // emissive: 0xff00ff,
    // emissiveIntensity: 1,
    skinning: true,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun.jpg'),
    color: 0xffffff,
    side: THREE.FrontSide
});
light.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1));
light.position.set(0,0,0);
light.castShadow = true;
```

Comment: If it doesn't work try replace `THREE.FrontSide` on `THREE.DoubleSide`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding emissive color and intensity would make it visible. Generally its a good idea to also add an ambient light whose intensity you can adjust based on the scene.

Im using a sphere with texture map with a point light and an ambient light. Both point light and sun are at origin

```
ambientLight params: 0xffffff,1
pointLight params 0xffffff, 10, 100, 0
emissive={'#FFA500'} 
emissiveIntensity={0.5}
```

And with this setup i get the result as expected [image]

PS: Since im using react three fiber some results might differ. However i confirmed without emissiveness my shere was also showing as black